# How is world data stored in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft worlds are huge; supposedly, [nearly 130 quadrillion blocks](http://htwins.net/scale2/). (Zoom out a little on that site and you'll see it.) Anyways, I looked in the Save folder (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves), and the world I'm currently playing in has a folder of the same name as my world. This folder is only 12 Mb. Does Minecraft really store 130 quadrillion blocks in 12 Mb, or is there some kind of insane level encoding going on? Even if there is crazy encoding ("Saving chunks", whatever that means) in the game itself, one does not simply fit 130 quadrillion blocks into well under one gigabyte of physical memory.

How does Minecraft store world data? As a programmer, I understand tilemaps that represent 1 or more blocks (in a 2D sense) per byte, and world data of that sort, but I can simply not wrap my mind around how 130 quadrillion blocks take up so little memory.

Comment: check out the wiki on it http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Anvil_file_format chunks are explained [here](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Chunks)

Comment: "one does not simply fit 130 quadrillion blocks into well under one gigabyte" .. You just made my day sir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is not 130 quadrillion blocks in a typical world save. The world is generated **as needed** and only the areas that are generated are saved. This means you are only saving a handful of chunks. A chunk in Minecraft is an area `16 x 16 x world height` blocks in size (currently 65536 blocks, previously 32768).

Comment: But theoretically, you will eventually explore all 130 quadrillion blocks, right? Obviously that would take hundreds of hours, but never mind that. Would the level data in that case just be massive?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson: Yep. But exploring the entire minecraft world isn't physically possible without some mod to speed you up or something in that vein.

Comment: @MathhewScharley: OK. In-game, are blocks stored in chunks? It seems like with things like dynamic lighting (given the precomputed lighting found in chunks) you would need some other data structure for world data.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson: Easiest way to prove this to yourself is to start a new map in creative mode and fly off in one direction and watch your save file grow

Comment: @LincolnBergeson: Now you're getting into the realm of gamedev.SE. I'm not 100% on the internals, but I do know that Minecraft loads and unloads a certain number of chunks around you (10[?]), which is slightly further than you can see. That would take care of the lighting issues, etc.

Comment: @MathhewScharley: Minecraft loads and unloads 10 chunks around me every frame? I'm impressed that my system can handle that at a decent frame rate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3777/discussion-between-lincoln-bergeson-and-matthew-scharley)

Comment: Actually what's stored are 256x256 x height region files, not chunk files.

Comment: @kotekzot: I'm not sure of the format of those files though. Those entire regions aren't generated and saved are they?

Comment: @kotekzot: what's the difference between region files and chunk files?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson: A region is just another delineation of an area. You can think of it as a group of chunks, where a chunk is a group of blocks. Specifically, a region is a group of 16x16 chunks.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson - Just because nobody else addressed this quite this explicitly, YES the world file would be massive (measured in gigabytes if not terabytes) if you generated every possible chunk.  However, there's no feasible way to do that in the game in a human lifetime.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that chunks are only saved if something was built or destroyed in it. Otherwise, the terrain generator rebuilds it as needed...

Comment: @Shinrai 180 quadrillion blocks at 2 bytes each would be over 360,000 terabytes, it would most certainly never fit in mere "gigabytes" if must generate every possible chunk

Answer (score 2):

The entire world is generated using seed values. Only user modified block data is stored as well as the seed. In my engine, I have what's called a region. It is composed of 16x16x16 chunks which are 16x16x16 cubes. 4096 cubes per chunk, 4096 chunks per region. An algorithm determines which faces of the cubes are visible and adds them to a vertex buffer. Only chunks within view are built. To generate an endless world chunks are recycled and built as you move. The number of chunks never changes. Cubes are stored as a byte array allowing you to have 255 block types. No other data is stored since face normals and other things are done programatically. A perlin noise and perlin worm algorithm are used to generate new world data as you move using the seed values. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct.  Chunks are saved as soon as they're generated.  Otherwise, updating your world to a version that changed land generation would change your entire world.

Answer (score 1):

Technically air does not exist, therefore the block data for air is stored as false or null, meaning Minecraft does not have to generate anything allowing for the file size to be much smaller. And as other people have said before, only the chunks you see are loaded, but that's not entirely true. Spawn chunks are always loaded therefore always saved, the rest is just compressed then saved.

Comment: False or null still needs to be stored. It's just very small compared to other blocks, and offers efficiencies for compression algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

Bear in mind that Minecraft almost certainly stores its world data using some form of compression, such as RLE (Run Length Encoding), which represents a string of identical blocks as (R16,A65,R1,W15), which basically says:

The next 16 blocks of the array are rock, followed by 65 blocks of air, followed by one block of rock, followed by 15 blocks of water... and so on.

Given the huge swaths of homogeneous material typically generated in a Minecraft chunk (especially up in the air), this sort of format can vastly reduce the amount of space needed to store it. Player construction will tend to chop up this space and make it less efficient by creating complex arrays of blocks and spaces - but even so in most places it would require vastly less storage space to represent the average chunk this way.

There are additional optimizations you could employ, but this is probably the simplest and most straightforward for a world like Minecraft.

Comment: The save file format is [well documented](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format). It uses [Zlib to compress block data within chunks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Region_file_format#Chunk_Data), which uses the same compression algorithm as Zip archives and PNG images.

Answer (score -6):

It is not 130 quadrillion because the sky limit is 42 blocks and the ground limit is 50 and the land limit is 136x2(both sides)do the math not 130 quadrillion (38841600 blocks)

Comment: World size has changed several times over Minecrafts life, and 'limits' are only enforced by certain world generators. The numbers are large and irrelevant to the question, given the observed filesize. Also, 'air' is still a block: specifically, it's a lack of a block. That emptiness still needs to be stored in some format, and Minecraft does (air is block id 0).

Comment: @MatthewScharley actually, air doesn't need to be stored. If you store all the blocks/values with position, air can easily be skipped. Anything not stored is air.